# BizTalk 2013 AS/2 issues

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Currently I'm working on a project on which I need to send a PDF file over AS/2 using BizTalk.
Now, everything is setup in BizTalk.

However, I have an error message in BizTalk saying the following:

```
The receive pipeline:"Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.DefaultPipelines.AS2Receive,        
Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiIntPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is trying to suspend a message received on Receive 
Location:"/xxx/BTSHTTPReceive.dll". The Adapter/Receive Location however is configured   
to never suspend messages on failure. Please change either the receive location or  
receive adapter's configuration or the pipeline's configuration.
```

If I configure the adapter to suspend messages on failure it does work partially. However, I want to get it working with this setup. Is there any way to figure our why my messages are being suspended?

The warning message that follows on the error is the following:

```
The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SendPDFToxxxxOverAS2" with   
URL "http://localhost/xxxx/BTSHTTPReceive.dll". It will be retransmitted after the retry  
interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"The remote server returned an error: 
(500) Internal Server Error.".
```

I hope someone can make some things clear.

In order to make narrow down the search, I've also removed the checkbox to send and request MDN's in the agreement.

Comment: What is the error on the BTSHTTPReceive.dll configured send port? And does this work for non PDF messages? Also - it looks like you are using the Edi pipeline - I'd be surprised if that works for non Edi content.

Comment: Hello, I only have the 2 messages that I've showed you above. I don't see anyhting else. And I use the AS2Send not the AS2EdiSend. I jope you can provide me some guidance.

Comment: There should be more information available about the 500 error you are seeing. Also, it looks like the problem is in your receive port - the error talks about AS2Receive and the EdiIntPipeline. If the server is not live, try changing to using non edi pipelines, and see what that does (may still error but should help you narrow it down).

Comment: Hey, I've checked it and when you select AS2 as the send pipeline the namespace is always Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt... Also, when I take the receive location (which is marked as HTTP) and I check "suspend failed requests" it's working partially (but files are transferred multiple times). Sorry for the maybe dumb questions but it's my very first BizTalk project.

Comment: But in the receive pipeline what is configured? The questions are fine - I used to specialize in BzTalk and AS2, but I've not worked with BizTalk for maybe five years, so this is dredging the depths of memory.

Comment: I don't have the receive pipeline, I just have a receive port and location which should pick up the file over HTTP of the BtsHttpReceiver.dll What kind of information do you need exactely ?

Comment: I'm still working on it. Now on the HTTP configure (receive location), as adviced on MSDN I've removed the flag on "Return correlation handle on success" and flagged "Suspend Failed Requests". Now the file is transmitted, but in the receive folder, I do have 2 files now, 2 pdf files, one if the original, the other one is a 0 bytes file. If I do check "Suspend Failed Requests" the file is removed from the input folder but doesn't appear anywhere. In other words, the file is lost. This is driving my cray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue myself.

"Return correlation handle on success" should be off.
"Suspend failed requests" should be on.

Thanks for the help anyway.

Kr